# How do I access a docker container on the local network?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  jellyfin:
    image: jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
    container_name: jellyfin
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: [gpu]
    user: 1000:1000
    network_mode: 'bridge'
    ports:
      - 8096:8096
    volumes:
      - /home/sai/Jellyfin/config:/config
      - /home/sai/Jellyfin/cache:/cache
      - /mnt/f/Music:/media:ro
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
```

This is my docker compose file. I can access the port 8096 on the host machine. Using docker on windows 11. I am very new to docker and am using it to host a Jellyfin server. I am unable to access this port from another device on my network, how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Inbound rule for port 8096 in your host machine